# How to avoid regex \r\n from being ignored the BigCommerce editor?

Tags: javascript, regex, bigcommerce

I am currently doing some work for my employer using the BigCommerce e-commerce software. On the site, you can edit the html off all the pages of your site.

My problem is that the editor ignores some regex. I'm trying to write some javascript, and when I try to use .replace, the editor strips some of my code. For example, I type:

```
content = content.replace(/\r\n/g, "<br />")
```

And when I save the page, the editor changes the code to this:

```
content = content.replace(/\
g, "<br />")
```

How can I work around this problem?

Comment: I don't know the software, but try `\\r\\n` instead of `\r\n` maybe?

Comment: it looks like a templating issue... your server side template is processing `\r\n` instead of printing it to the page...

Comment: what is the server side technology used to generate the page

Comment: I'm quite sure BigCommerce has their own tech for generating the pages.

Comment: BigCommerce use something called "Design Mode" which is their in-browser editor. I don't think there is an alternative, either.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the "Design Mode" editor. Update the particular file you want to work on via Webdav. Should upload properly without stripping out anything.